# bcdedit is having big time delay

Tags: boot, performance, bootloader, bcdedit, msconfig

I want to read and set default entries in Windows Boot Manager from my app by bcdedit. But bcdedit is very slow. For response from bcdedit I must wait about 16 seconds. Why is bcdedit too slow or how to mange Windows Boot Manager faster?

For example `msconfig` does what I want to do automatically in my program but works without time delay. How can I do it as fast as msconfig?

Answer (score 0):

BCDedit is pretty fast on BIOS.

BCDedit could be slower on UEFI because it syncs NVRAM with BCD and BCD copy in registry. (On BIOS there is no NVRAM)

NVRAM holds UEFI boot variables. BCD on UEFI contains a copy of some NVRAM boot variables like Windows boot manager entry from disk, attachable boot devices like USB, DVD.

Comment: Is there any other option how to do it fast on UEFI?

Comment: If you don't change {fwbootmgr}, {bootmgr}, or efi loaders bcdedit should be fast enough. I don't know how Windows manages internally the sync between BCD, registry and NVRAM and how exactly it is triggered. I can hardly imagine a faster way of changing BCD than using bcdedit (written by M$ system programmers).